# PHP: Zipping files as xlsx causes file to become invalid

Tags: php, zip, excel-2007, xlsx, php-ziparchive

I have to replace variables inside a user-submitted xlsx file and am doing it this way:

1. Rename the .xlsx to .zip
2. Unzip to a temp-folder
3. Make the necessary changes
4. Zip the files
5. Rename the .zip to .xslx

I am using plain ZipArchive in PHP. When I try to open the generated .xlsx in Excel, it fails with a message `format or extension invalid`. When I compress the temporary files with WinRAR (as zip), and rename the resulting file to .xlsx, it works. The zip files generated with both methods contain the same data structure and files, but the WinRAR file is slightly bigger (10.2K vs. 10.3K with normal compression).

When viewing the garbled code of the files, I could see that the files appear in a different order, but don't know if that's the cause. Any clue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Zip allows for a few different compression methods. Possibly the zip generated one isn't supported by Office, while WinRar uses a method that IS supported.

Comment: If you're using ZipArchive on a Windows box, there have been some buggy versions of php_zip.dll that create a corrupted zip when writing

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far - but what should I do? Is there an alternate zipping component for PHP? @Mark Baker: Can I test the validity of the zip file? Opening the ZipArchive-generated file in WinRAR does not throw an error, so it seems valid.

Comment: It's an issue that has caused me a great deal of strife over the last 18 months or so.I'm not aware of any simple fix for this problem, other than to try and locate a fairly recent version of php_zip.dll that you can prove works, and stick with that.

Comment: Alternatively, there is a sourceforge project that provides a compatible php wrapper for the zip/unzip binaries at https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=254316

Comment: @Mark Baker - I got it to work with another component, PclZip (http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip). It is a class that apparently uses gzip, and renaming it's outputs to .xlsx are fine with Excel 2007. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with another component, PclZip (phpconcept.net/pclzip). It is a class that apparently uses gzip, and renaming it's outputs to .xlsx are fine with Excel 2007.